# Android: change font color on click

Tags: android, button, text, colors

i am trying to change the color of text inside a button.

So for example i have a button which is filled with white and the text is blue. When i click on the button i want these two colors to swap (text inside the button becomes white and the button blue).

I have tried something like this:

```
 <item style="@style/ButtonText_Menue_Clicked" android:drawable="@drawable/button_menue_default" android:state_focused="true"></item>
 <item style="@style/ButtonText_Menue" android:drawable="@drawable/button_menue_default" ></item>
```

but it actually does nothing. 
Is there any way to do what i want, or do i have to do some stuff in the onclik event (but then there is the problem how to set the colors back when the "click is gone" )

Comment: As far as I know you need to do it in onClick. Pretty simple code.

Comment: and how do i change it back ?

Comment: and there you also have the problem that the text changes just when you fulfill the click. But i want the button text to change before i relase the button (and onclick is called after releasing the button)

Comment: you could do it using a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html), and set it as the textColor

Comment: i didnt use it before. i will look into it and check if it can help me to do what i want :) thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Misread what you were trying to do, sorry :P

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Create a `selector` resource in `res/color` for the text color and a button `selector` in `res/drawable` as below...

text_color.xml

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#800000" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="#4C5" />
</selector>
```

button_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#4C5"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <solid android:color="#800000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Add the button to the layout

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:background="@drawable/button_color"/>
```

Comment: great, that was just the thing i was looking for, thanks

Comment: text_color.xml is a [Color State List Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html), so I think put it in a `color` directory is better than in `drawable` because set a drawable to `textColor` is confusing.