# How do i change text color when button was pressed once (Android)

Tags: android

what i basically wanna do is this:
When i click on the button i want its Text color to appear in a different color.
What i tried is this:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/red" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="#000" />
</selector>
```

and then i did use this selector as drawable on the button android:textColor

but this doesn solve it since it only changes its color while i press the button.
I want it like this:
Default: black
on click: blue
on click again: black

any ideas how to do that? :S

this is my shape for the button (if it matters):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="-1dp"
    android:insetLeft="-1dp"
    android:insetRight="-1dp">
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="false">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners
                    android:radius="0dp"
                    />
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/background_grey"
                    />
                <padding
                    android:left="0dp"
                    android:top="0dp"
                    android:right="0dp"
                    android:bottom="0dp"
                    />
                <size
                    android:width="100dp"
                    android:height="30dp"
                    />
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#ffb4b4b4"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners
                    android:radius="0dp"
                    />
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/pq_blue"
                    />
                <padding
                    android:left="0dp"
                    android:top="0dp"
                    android:right="0dp"
                    android:bottom="0dp"
                    />
                <size
                    android:width="100dp"
                    android:height="30dp"
                    />
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#ffb4b4b4"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
</inset>
```

thx in advance

**EDIT**

so i tried to do it programatically and tied the folowing just to see if it changes color´s ..but yea..it doesn´t (it seems like my onCLick event doesnt work):

```
 @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, container, false);



    final Button likeButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btLike);
    likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String test = "tester";
            if(BUTTON_STATE==BUTTON_STATE_ONCE){

                likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pq_blue));
                BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_TWICE;
            }else{
                likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_ONCE;
            }

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

}

NOTE: i do all tht stuff in onCreateView since im in a Fragment of my ActionBarActivity(with tabs) if im doing it in the onCreate i get a null pointer exception at findViewById ( since it searches for the ID in my mainActivity, if im right?)

so yea..any ideas?

Comment: if You want a behaviour like this, You have to do it programmatically. A selector cannot get the state of second or third click

Comment: You don't want to do it programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: change font color on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675656/android-change-font-color-on-click)

Comment: Is any of this answers a solution for You? I think You get misunderstood, maybe I had misunderstood You, but Your goal is: default:black, then first click:blue, then second click:black. Isn´t it?

Comment: ok thx...so i really need to do it programmatically. Is there a commo/easy way to do it?or just handle it with onClickListener, change color there and set some state/flag so it knows that it changed the color. then make If(state) change color back to normal?

Comment: btw when is android:state_focused triggered? whats the difference between state_focused and state_pressed?

Comment: see my answer. The problem is, focused will give You maybe the other color, but if any other view gets pressed, the button looses the focus and the color goes back. State focused stands for: the button is pressed until another view gets pressed.

Comment: @zooky just use the code in my answer it will do exactly what you want without selector

Comment: I see Your mistake...please follow my example, create two global variables and use them in the if else example like I´ve done it...I will edit the example to Your code...

Answer (score 2):

Your textselector.xml -

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/red" /> <!--selected text colour-->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/red" />
    <item            
        android:color="@color/blue" /> <!--unselected text colour-->
</selector>
```

Your button in layout.xml -

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:textColor="@drawable/textselector" <!-- SET textselector HERE -->
    android:background="@drawable/button_color"/>
```

Comment: the button will loose the state focused if another view gets clicked, so the textcolor will change back to black, also without click a third time....

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to do it programmatically:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ColorStateList myList=myButton.getTextColors();
        int myColor=myList.getDefaultColor();
        switch(myColor)
        {
            case Color.BLACK:
            myButton.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;

            case Color.BLUE:
            myButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            break;

       }
   }
});
```

Comment: but isn´t it like this, with getDefaultColor(), You will allways get the black one because this is set as default in the selector?.....so the switch state will not get the correct state...

Comment: Well I just tested it and it is working for me of course I don't have that xml styling in mine and also consider that getTextColors(); gets the current color not getDefaultColor();

Comment: ok, but in the API it´s defined: "Gets the text colors for the different states (normal, selected, focused)....". That means to me, all used colors will be inside the ColorStateList, also the default one, or?

Comment: getDefaultColor(); returns the default color in this ColorStateList not the only original one so when programmatically Button's color changes without saying for which state(pressed,focused,...) it would be default color.

Comment: ah You mean the default color which defined in xml layout of the button, not the selector one?

Answer (score 1):

If You want to have a behaviour like:

- First Click: Button text black
- Second Click: Button text blue
- third Click: button text black again

I don´t think it´s possible with the selector, also not with state focused. Because if any other view will be clicked, the button is not focused anymore and will loose the textcolor, goes back to default. You have to do it in a programmatically way:

First, set the default textColor to what You want: black inside Your xml. So than You have the color on no press. make a globa variabel to save the state:

```
 private int BUTTON_STATE = 0;
 private final int BUTTON_STATE_ONCE = 0;
 private final int BUTTON_STATE_TWICE = 1;



     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          if(BUTTON_STATE==BUTTON_STATE_ONCE){

            button.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_TWICE;
          }else if(BUTTON_STATE==BUTTON_STATE_TWICE){

            button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_ONCE;
          }

        }

    });
```

That´s just a possible solution, there are many ways..

### EDIT

for Your code:

Create that global variables like i did in my example above, and use them in the if/else statement:

```
    likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

           if(BUTTON_STATE==BUTTON_STATE_ONCE){

        likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pqBlue));
        BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_TWICE;
      }else if(BUTTON_STATE==BUTTON_STATE_TWICE){

        likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pqBlack));
        BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_ONCE;
      }

    }
});
```

Comment: i wanted to do it like that but it doesnt change the color... any idea why? Check my comment below this.. i cant display it properly in a comment tho. Im doing all that in my Fragment thats why its in onCreateView and thats why i use rootView.findViewById etc. (it wants the button to be final..idk if its because of this)

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, container, false);

            final Button likeButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btLike);
            likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }

Comment: can You update Your post? It´s hard to read code from a comment. And have You defined the states like in my example, also the if else statements?

Comment: this doesnt work since it wants BUTTON_STATE to be final because its used in an inner class...if u put it final you cant change the value :S  I think this is why i cant change the color if i only write down: likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pqBlue)); because my button is final and cant be changed then..is that possible? If thats the point then ive a problem because it has to be final (same as above...ussage in inner class) :S

Comment: No, You have to make these variables global, not inside the class.

Comment: i tried that also but then i get this: Non-static field BUTTON_STATE cannot be referenced from a stati content. i get this on this lines:if(BUTTON_STATE==BUTTON_STATE_ONCE) and BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_TWICE;  and BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_ONCE;  lets say i just wanna change the color once..then it would be enough to say  ....setTextColor(...) right? but this doesnt work either..is it because of the "final" -> final button likeButton ..

Comment: then You can make these Variables static,  like  private static int BUTTON_STATE = 0;

Comment: ok i did that..still doesnt work. It seems like it doesnt even jump into my onClick funtion :O need to figure that out... if u want u can take a look at it. ill update my 1st post

Comment: is the button R.id.btLike part of the layout xml R.layout.listview_item ?

Comment: please try one thing, make a Toast in if else statement, one for if, one for else. If nothing of both is shown a toast, we can be sure, that onClick is not reached and find the mistake..

Comment: nothing is shown..i also tried it with log.d ..nothing too

Comment: can You send me the source code please? I think we have to look at another place for the issue: opiatefuchs@gmail.com

Comment: you are my hero.Your solution just save my life. @Opiatefuchs thank you very much,if possible,I give u 10 likes..haha

Answer (score 0):

Try adding text_effect.xml drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="@color/white" /> <!-- pressed -->    
     <item android:color="@color/black" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

add this line in button control

```
android:textColor="@drawable/text_effect"
```

It will work. Enjoy:)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mandatorily need a simple Button, you could use a ToggleButton that is made for binary-state handling... With a ToggleButton your selector would look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/red" />
   <!-- Default State -->
   <item android:color="#000" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wanna implement something like toggle button.
Instead of button u can use toggle button.
Though if you wanna use button only then u need to do some changes in your java code as well as xml code also

Create a file **def_btn.xml** it will look like this..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/background_grey"
                />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp"
                />
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="30dp"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffb4b4b4"
                />
        </shape>
```

Create another file **press_btn.xml** it will look like this..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/pq_blue"
                />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp"
                />
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="30dp"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffb4b4b4"
                />
        </shape>
```

Inside your activity declare a private boolean variable(say isPressed) by default isPressed is false. & for default button background will be def_btn.xml

Now write following in button's onClick event.

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isPressed = !isPressed;

            if(isPressed){
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.def_btn);
            }else{
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.press_btn);
            }
        }
    });
```

That's it..

Comment: i dont want a togle under my text tho. And a togle button always delivers a "bar" under the text doesnt it ?