# how to initate Button in a ListFragment

Tags: java, android

I have a more or less complex problem. I'll try to describe it:

It all started with this problem:
[How do i change text color when button was pressed once (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558164/how-do-i-change-text-color-when-button-was-pressed-once-android/28558758?noredirect=1#comment45438176_28558758)

So I have a `LoginActivity` which is my start activity. After you're logged in you will get to my "`mainActivity`" which extends `ActionBarActivity` and has swipeable tabs. In these tabs I inflate my "designed" custom Fragments.

The class looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, PinboardFragment.OnPinboardInteractionListener, CurrentPageFragment.OnCurrentPageInteractionListener, UserFragment.OnUserInteractionListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    static int  BUTTON_STATE = 0;
    final static int BUTTON_STATE_ONCE = 0;
    final static int BUTTON_STATE_TWICE = 1;
    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    //IconArray for actionBar
    final int[] ACTIONBAR_ICONS = new int[] {
            R.drawable.ic_action_pinboard_white,
            R.drawable.ic_action_recent_white,
            R.drawable.ic_action_groups_white,
    };

    final int[] ACTIONBAR_ICONS_BLACK= new int[] {
            R.drawable.ic_action_pinboard,
            R.drawable.ic_action_recent,
            R.drawable.ic_action_groups,
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);  // hides action bar icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); // hides action bar title

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });



        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setIcon(MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(ACTIONBAR_ICONS[i]))
                            .setTabListener(this));





        }



    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        //if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //    return true;
        //}

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.

        int pos = tab.getPosition();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        switch (pos){
            case 0:
                actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_section1));
                actionBar.getTabAt(pos).setIcon(MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(ACTIONBAR_ICONS_BLACK[pos]));
            break;
            case 1:
                actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_section2));
                actionBar.getTabAt(pos).setIcon(MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(ACTIONBAR_ICONS_BLACK[pos]));
            break;
            case 2:
                actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_section3));
                actionBar.getTabAt(pos).setIcon(MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(ACTIONBAR_ICONS_BLACK[pos]));
            break;

            default:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Intranet");
        }
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        int pos = tab.getPosition();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        switch (pos){
            case 0:
                actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_section1));
                actionBar.getTabAt(pos).setIcon(MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(ACTIONBAR_ICONS[pos]));
                break;
            case 1:
                actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_section2));
                actionBar.getTabAt(pos).setIcon(MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(ACTIONBAR_ICONS[pos]));
                break;
            case 2:
                actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_section3));
                actionBar.getTabAt(pos).setIcon(MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(ACTIONBAR_ICONS[pos]));
                break;

            default:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Intranet");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    @Override
    public void OnPinboardInteractionListener(String id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void OnCurrentPageInteractionListener(String id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void OnUserInteractionListener(String id) {

    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    return PinboardFragment.newInstance("aab", "bcb");
                case 1:
                    return CurrentPageFragment.newInstance("a", "b");
                case 2:
                    return UserFragment.newInstance("a","b");
                default:
                    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    //return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    //return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    //return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, container, false);



            final Button likeButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btLike);
            final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
            likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if(BUTTON_STATE==BUTTON_STATE_ONCE){
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"if");

                        likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pq_blue));
                        BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_TWICE;
                    }else{
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"else");
                        likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pq_blue));
                        BUTTON_STATE = BUTTON_STATE_ONCE;
                    }

                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

So I found out that my `onCreateView` is only used for the `placeholderFragments` and since I don't use them (because I inflate my own) I never reach the initalization of my "`likeButton`" and that's why it doesn't change its color. So I guess I need to initialize it in my `PinboardFragment` but I don't know how to. Since it extends `ListFragment` it only has an `onCreate` method and not an `onCreateView`. So I tried to make my own `onCreateMethode` but it crashes. So how do I get my buttons initialized properly? Maybe I already made a mistake on my `MainActivity`? Maybe i don't need those `placeholderFragments` and can use my `PinboardFragment` instead?

here is my `pinboardFragment` Code:

```
public class PinboardFragment extends ListFragment{

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private List<ListViewItem> mItems; // ListView items list

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnPinboardInteractionListener mListener;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    public static PinboardFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PinboardFragment fragment = new PinboardFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public PinboardFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // initialize the items list
        mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
        Resources resources = getResources();
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.profile),"Danny", " 4 minutes","Hallo "));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.profile), "Danny", "vor 1 Stunde"," So ungefähr soll das ganze aussehen ;) "));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.profile), "youtube", "am 21.01.2014 um 18:49 ", "test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test  test test test test test test test test test "));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.profile),"Danny Sk","Gestern um 21:59 ","Heading to dreamhack winter finals with some pro friend called pr0kemon - stay tuned"));
        // initialize and set the list adapter
        setListAdapter(new PinboardListViewAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnPinboardInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnScoutLogInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        if (null != mListener) {
            // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
            // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
            //mListener.OnScoutLogInteraction(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
        }
    }



    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnPinboardInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void OnPinboardInteractionListener(String id);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item,
                container, false);
        final Button likeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btLike);
        likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pq_blue));
            }

        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

I'm quite new to android programming so I may have some major issues. If you find some or something, feel free to tell me that. I'm thankful for every help I can get.

I also thought about to solve it with the `onInteraction` methods. But right now I have no clue what they are for. :D

I hope it's not to much text/code. :D

Thanks for any help!

In short: where/how should I initiate my buttons so I can react on `onClick` events and change the color of the text on my buttons.

**EDIT:1 more question**
Why can't I use the `onCreateView` method in my `PinboardFragment` and inflate it from there? :S Like posted above.

Comment: Are you sure "R.layout.listview_item" contains your Button (R.id.btLike)?
The documentation is quite important... Look at this:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
Btw: Getting started in Android is not easy, but keep on track - things will get more clear soon.

Comment: yea im sure about that :)